# MPMoviePlayerViewController weared animation on done?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6, ios5.1, mpmovieplayer

```
self.moviePlayerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pathToFile]];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.moviePlayerViewController];
```

MoviePlayer is displaying.But clicking on done button it dismiss with some wiered behavior.
Ideally movie player should dismiss like a normal `dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated` but my control is appearing like a present animation and my controller will cover the movieplayer.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below & check if this work for you or not:

```
moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
[moviePlayerController.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
moviePlayerController.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=YES;
moviePlayerController.view.frame = self.view.frame;
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerController];
[moviePlayerController.moviePlayer play];
```